# msi file not running when called through wix customaction

Tags: wix, custom-action, impersonation

I have the following in my wix project but the msi file (which is valid and runs from the command line) will not run either with or without the silent parameter

```
<InstallExecuteSequence >
  <Custom Action="Runmymsi" After="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 5):

I have run into this before. Your issue is that you can't call an MSI from another MSI. These need to be run at separate times. I would suggest writing a bootstrapper that will run your MSIs in the proper sequence.

Comment: Scott is right. If you don't want to use a bootstrapper you can also try using a simple EXE or BAT custom action which launches the other MSI through MSIEXEC.EXE or through ShellExecute.

Comment: @Cosmin: Dead on. We use a C# written exe the uses msiexec. This also allows us to verbose log in a more accessible location.